# Trocar por regex formato '0,00' por formato '0.00'

Tags: regex

Preciso fazer uma inserção no banco de dados, mas me enviaram o sql para importação com a cultura(globalização ou sei lá o que) errada.

Dessa forma os números no SQL estão nesse formato:

```
'0,0 ou '0,00' ou '00,00' ou '000,00' ou seja, aspa simples + numero(s) + virgula + numero(s) + aspa simples
```

Mas eu preciso deles nesse formato:

```
'0.0 ou '0.00' ou '00.00' ou '000.00'
```

Gostaria através do notepad++ fazer um replace em todo o sql que trocasse essas vírgulas por pontos, mas somente nos valores que estão nesse formato, pois existem muitas outras virgulas nesse sql que devem se manter.

É possível fazer isso?

Exemplo de um insert que quero usar o replace:

```
Insert into TB_META (COD_META,COD_CONFIGURACAO,COD_OBJETIVO,COD_UG_RESPONSAVEL,TIP_META,TXT_DESCRICAO,TIP_LEITURA,TIP_MEDIDA_META,TIP_FORMA_CALCULO,VAL_MINIMO,VAL_MEDIO,VAL_MAXIMO,DATA_INATIVACAO,NUM_PERIODO_INATIVACAO,COD_CONFIGURACAO_INATIVACAO,TXT_METRICA_CALC,TXT_EVIDENCIAS) values ('209','8','91','742','E','Gerar xxxxxxxxxxx.','>   ','%   ','U','5,53','6,5','7,48',null,null,null,'Ganhos xxxxxxxx','Métrica aprovada em xxxxxx.');
```

Nesse caso o '7,48' tem que virar '7.48' o '5,53' tem que virar '5.53' e '6,5' tem que virar '6.5'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta usar essa regex na busca: (\d+),(\d+)

e essa string pra substituir: \1.\2